# -[UIDragSession loadObjectsOfClass:completion:] completionBlock not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm learning iOS11 new APIs Drag and Drop, but I have some questions.
I have two collectionViews which share same type (**DataEntity**) of dataSource array. One is for drag and the other is for drop. That means I want to drag item which contains data (**DataEntity**) from one collectionView to another.

Then I have the question in `[-(id<UICollectionDropDelegate>)collectionView:performDropWithCoordinator:]`. I can't fetch data (**DataEntity**) passed in my first collectionView because `-[UIDragSession loadObjectsOfClass:completion:]` completionBlock is not being called. However, if I set other class (such as UIImage.class or NSString.class) to parameter `loadObjectsOfClass:` completion block will get called, however it is not the compatible class so there's no return objects.

**Source Code**

Drag collectionView

```
- (NSArray<UIDragItem *> *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView itemsForBeginningDragSession:(id<UIDragSession>)session atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    DataEntity* entity = self.entities[indexPath.row];
    UIDragItem* item = [[UIDragItem alloc] initWithItemProvider:[[NSItemProvider alloc] initWithObject:entity]];
    return @[item];
}
```

Drop collectionView

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView performDropWithCoordinator:(id<UICollectionViewDropCoordinator>)coordinator {
    NSIndexPath* destinationIndexPath = coordinator.destinationIndexPath;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
            [coordinator.session loadObjectsOfClass:DataEntity.class completion:^(NSArray<__kindof id<NSItemProviderReading>> * _Nonnull objects) {
                [objects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(__kindof id<NSItemProviderReading>  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
                    [self.mutableEntities insertObject:(DataEntity*)obj atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
                    [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[destinationIndexPath]];
                }];
            }];
        } completion:nil];
    });
}
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView canHandleDropSession:(id<UIDropSession>)session {
    BOOL test = [session canLoadObjectsOfClass:DataEntity.class]; // It's YES
    return test;
}
```

Data entity

```
- (NSProgress *)loadDataWithTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)typeIdentifier forItemProviderCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSData * _Nullable, NSError * _Nullable))completionHandler {
    NSData* data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self];
    completionHandler(data, nil);
    return nil;
}
+ (NSArray<NSString *> *)writableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider {
    NSString* identifier = NSStringFromClass(self.class);
    return @[identifier];
}
+ (NSArray<NSString *> *)readableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider {
    NSString* identifier = NSStringFromClass(self.class);
    return @[identifier];
}
+ (nullable instancetype)objectWithItemProviderData:(nonnull NSData *)data typeIdentifier:(nonnull NSString *)typeIdentifier error:(NSError * _Nullable __autoreleasing * _Nullable)outError {
    DataEntity* entity = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    return entity;
}
```

**EDIT**

Ok, I found something.
First, if I remove the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())`, I will get an error **unrecoginized selector -[DataEntity encodeWithCoder:]**. And that is the second thing, I forget to make **DataEntity** conform to **NSCoding** protocol.

Now the new question is, why I can't call `-[UIDragSession loadObjectsOfClass:completion:]` in **dispatch_main_queue** closure, or its completion block won't be called?

Comment: Is your `objectWithItemProviderData` being called?

Comment: @matt No. `readableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider ` and `writableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider ` will get being called. `loadDataWithTypeIdentifier ` and `objectWithItemProviderData ` not called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all has to do with the basic principles of asynchronous code execution. In your implementation of `collectionView:performDropWithCoordinator:`, this code is wrong:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [coordinator.session loadObjectsOfClass: // ...
```

When you call `dispatch_async`, you allow the call to `collectionView:performDropWithCoordinator:` to return — it comes to an end! But you are doing that *before* you proceed to load the data. Therefore the drop ends immediately and the session disappears, *before* you have a chance to pick up the data. When we get to `loadObjectsOfClass`, there is no data any more; the session has already ended.

In fact, I bet the `session` at that point is `nil`. And code sent to a `nil` object does nothing; that's why your `objectWithItemProviderData` and the completion handler are never called.